# How to retrieve only certain fields of an entity in JPQL or HQL? What is the equivalent of ResultSet in JPQL or HQL?

Tags: hibernate, orm, hql, jpql

In JPQL, I can retrieve entities by :

```
query = entityManager.createQuery("select c from Category c");
List<Category> categories = query.getResultList();
```

But, if I wish to retrieve the id and name fields (only) of the Category entity, I need something like the `ResultSet` object, through which I can say : `rs.getString("name")` and `rs.getString("id")`. How to do this through `JPQL`, without retrieving the entire entity ?

Basically, for a how to retrieve information from a query like : `select c.id,c.name from Category c` ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In HQL you can use list() function to get a list of Object[] array that contains result rows:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select c.id,c.name from Category c");
List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
```

in returned array 1-st element will be id, second - name.

```
for (Object[] row: rows) {
    System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
    System.out.println("id: " + row[0]);
    System.out.println("name: " + row[1]);
}
```

If you want to use hibernate's Criteria API, you should use [Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection).

With JPA it will work the same way:

```
List<Object[]> rows = entityManager.createQuery(queryString).getResultList();
```

Comment: I see queries like : "select c.id,c.name from Category c" often in  JPA books, but they never tell u how to retrieve the results. Any way to do it without being Hibernate specific ?

Comment: With JPA it will work the same way. I added example to my answer. But note that if you will, for example, select only name column - then you will get the List<String>, not List<Object[]>.

Comment: What is the `session` variable in this context? `org.hibernate.Session` does not have a `createQuery` method, at least in 4.3.

Answer (score 12):

It is not the use of the `.list()` function itself which makes the result a `List<Object[]>`. It is the specification of fields (`c.id, c.name`) in the HQL query. If your query is

```
    "select c from Category c"
```

Then `query.list()` will return a `List<Category>` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can also directly map to the class

```
public class UserData {

    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    private String password;
//setter
}



  public UserData getUserData() {
        String queryString = "select user.name as name, user.dob as dob, user.userses.password as password from UserProfile user where user.userEmailId='faiz.krm@gmail.com'";
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);
        query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserData.class));
        return query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**The JPA specification allows us to customize results in an object-oriented fashion.**

More information you can find at this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions#solution_constructor)

There is an even more **elegant** [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40934100/9183844)