# How to retrieve specific columns in Paginated way using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have One entity class, its service and repository as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "emp_code")
    private String empCode;
    // ... other properties
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String>
{
    // .... working 
    @Query("select u.userName from User u")
    Page<User> findAllUserName(Pageable pageable);


    //... not working
    @Query("select u.userName, u.empCode from User u")
    Page<User> findAllUserNameAndEmpCode(Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I am trying to execute `findAllUserName` it works properly. but when using `findAllUserNameAndEmpCode`.. it throws following exceptions **while starting tomcat**:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found ',' near line 1, column 29 [select count(u.userName,u.empCode) from com.entity.User u]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1778)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
... 63 more
```

I dont know why, and how its converting this query to `SELECT count(..)` ? What is meaning of `expecting CLOSE, found ','` ??
Please help.. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Page<String> findAllUserName(Pageable pageable); ?
BTW the SELECT count(..) is fired because of Page return value so that you know total number of elements matching your criteria.

Comment: @daerin question updated btw. `findAllUserName` works properly but when trying to return two column its giving error. in case of `findAllUserNameAndEmpCode`.. application gives error while starting.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns

Comment: @daerin Thanks.. I looked at it initially.. it works.. but result is not paginated.. somehow I need `Page<Class>` entity to be returned

Comment: why do you need to limit the columns. Can't you just find all. I doubt your User class contains too much anyway for any optimization to be needed

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen Yes User class contains other properties too.. and one simply may not want to return all those properties if he only require few columns at client side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should specify the count query. The Page return value of your select function needs to know how many results there will be. So it sends a COUNT query that is probably made from your select query and looks like this:

```
select count(u.userName,u.empCode) from com.entity.User u
```

which is wrong because COUNT function takes only one parameter. So you should create your custom count query (probably like this):

```
select count(u.userName) from com.entity.User u
```

and place it into `@Query` annotation:

```
@Query(
    value = "select u.userName, u.empCode from User u",
    countQuery = "select count(u.userName) from com.entity.User u"
)
Page<User> findAllUserNameAndEmpCode(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: in spring data version 4.x, it is no need set @Query's countQuery prop.