# what is the right jpa query to get some column from table instead of all table data

Tags: spring, jpa

I am getting this given exception

*Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.freeGo.model.Pump   at com.freeGo.util.HealthTask.run(HealthTask.java:33)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)*

My code is :

```
@Query("SELECT p.id, p.timestamp FROM Pump p WHERE p.isActive = :isActive")
 public List<Pump> findByIsActive(@Param("isActive") int isActive);
```

if i don't use Query annotation as

```
public List<Pump> findByIsActive(@Param("isActive") int isActive);
```

then it's run successfully, but it return's all table data but i want only 2 column.

My project in spring-3 and jpa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the query, if that's what you want. You will be getting a object[] (object array) from the query instead of a `List<Pump>`. So, make the return type `List<Object[]>` and get id in column 0 and time in column 1.

If you want to make it a little better code, you should probably get the query to return a custom DTO.

```
@Query("SELECT new MyDto(p.id, p.timestamp) FROM Pump p WHERE p.isActive = :isActive")
```

and return a `List<MyDto>`

Reference: [Spring JPA selecting specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns)