# Get specific columns in an array from Spring JPA Method

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to get a simple `List<String[]` representing 2 columns from a Spring JPA Method inside a `CrudRepository` class?

Example:

```
@Transactional
public interface ProjectDao extends CrudRepository<Project, Integer> {

    @Transactional
    @Query("SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1") 
    public List<String[]> get2Columns();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns#29020641

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't know how to do it in my case :/

Comment: Up please I still blocked

Comment: So what does happen when you try it?