# jpql constructor expression query org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

i am using spring data jpa , i want to retrieve specific columns from postgres table, i followed couple of links to retrieve specific columns [Spring JPA selecting specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns)
i found regarding jpql constructor expression query to retrieve specific columns,

i used the jpql expression on the respository class

```
public interface DeviceCrudRepository  extends CrudRepository<Device,String>{
public Device findByBarcode(String barcode);

@Query(value = "select new com.hello.world.model.Device (d.deviceName,d.deviceType,d.deviceDescription ,d.deviceRentalStatus) from devicedetails d where d.scancode=:scancode", nativeQuery = true)
public Device findDeviceDetailsByBarcode(@Param("d.scancode") String d.scancode);
```

Model class is 
 i am using constructor too

```
public Device(String deviceName, String deviceType, String deviceDescription, String deviceRentalStatus) {
        super();
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
        this.deviceType = deviceType;
        this.deviceDescription = deviceDescription;
        this.deviceRentalStatus = deviceRentalStatus;
    }
```

I keep on getting exception

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 15
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]

when i checked in logs 
the query which was generated was

```
select new com.hello.world.model.Device (d.deviceName,d.deviceType,d.deviceDescription ,d.deviceRentalStatus) from devicedetails d where d.scancode=?
```

it's  not able to translate the jpql expression into query,it's showing exception for package name, when i use the class name it's showing exception near the brackets, so i guess the jpql expression is not being translated 
am i missing any dependency any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **PGSQL** is not **JPQL** it's normal that it do not understand your query :) Remove the `nativeQuery = true`.