# JPQL Query with entity constructor

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm having trouble with building a query that groups 'Smoke' entity by their 'activity' column and sums 'quantity' of them.
Query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.eminyilmazz.smoketracker.dto.ActivityBasedQuantity(s.activity, SUM(s.quantity)) FROM smoke s WHERE s.smoked_date BETWEEN :beginDate AND :endDate GROUP BY s.activity", nativeQuery = true)
List<ActivityBasedQuantity> getTotalQuantityGroupedByActivityWithMinuteInterval(@Param("beginDate")LocalDateTime beginDate, @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate);
```

DTO:

```
public class ActivityBasedQuantity {
    private String activity;
    private Long quantity;

    public ActivityBasedQuantity(String activity, Long quantity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
```

The first line in the error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT new com.eminyilmazz.smoketracker.dto.ActivityBasedQuantity(s.activity, SUM(s.quantity)) FROM smoke s WHERE s.smoked_date BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY s.activity]; SQL [n/a]
```

I've tried removing "nativeQuery = true" that is suggested from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479705/jpql-constructor-expression-query-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception) but it throws an error that says spring bean factory and hibernate couldn't resolve 'smoke' table and its attributes.

Comment: Your query doesn't seem to be a native query.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you're correct. I realized I didn't know what nativeQuery stands for and how I need to modify my query. I did some more research and fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue with these changes;

Replaced 'smoke' to 'Smoke' (typo)

Removed 'nativeQuery = true'

```
@Query("SELECT new com.eminyilmazz.smoketracker.dto.ActivityBasedQuantity(s.activity, SUM(s.quantity)) FROM Smoke s WHERE s.smokedDate BETWEEN :beginDate AND :endDate GROUP BY s.activity")
    List<ActivityBasedQuantity> getTotalQuantityGroupedByActivityWithMinuteInterval(@Param("beginDate")LocalDateTime beginDate, @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate);
```