# Extract only certain fields using CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using `CrudRepository` to fetch `Persons` from database.

Is it possible to only fetch certain fields from the db, instead of the full entity, using a CrudRepository mapping method?

Example: I only want to extract all `lastname` column fields:

```
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    //of course this is invalid
    List<String> findAllLastname();
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;


    private String firstname, lastname;
}
```

`findAllLastname()` is of course not valid, but can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer help?
[Spring JPA selecting specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch specific field just doing this:

```
@Query("select p.lastName from Person p")
List<String> getAllLastName();
```

But sometimes this may not work (for example [for enum type](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1338)).
The best way here, IMO, is using [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) as returned type, for example:

```
public interface PersonProjection {
    String getLastName();
}

@Query("select p.lastName as lastName from Person p")
List<PersonProjection> getAllPersonProjections();
```

In this case if you need to get, in the future, not only the `lastName` but also `firstName` then you simple update your `PersonProjection` and the query method:

```
public interface PersonProjection {
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
}

@Query("select p.firstName as firstName, p.lastName as lastName from Person p")
List<PersonProjection> getAllPersonProjections();
```

Note that you should use aliases of the entity fields (`p.firstName as firstName`) that correspond to names of getters in the projection.

Comment: This looks primising. Does that work without the `@Query` too, means the query is autogenerated from spring by method name?

Comment: Projections should work without `@Query`, but getting single field - doesn't.

Comment: @membersound without `@Query` you should correctly name your query method, like `findAllBy()`

Comment: I just discovered one does only require an *interface* with the getters accordingly. No `@Projection` from `spring-data-rest` is required at all. That's very neat!

Answer (score 2):

Giving a Query annotation with the specific SQL query should work

```
@Query("select p.lastName from Person  p")
List<Person> getAllLastName();
```

Comment: Ok I thought it would be possible without writing sql explicit.

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible. JPA returns the entire object because it is probably as efficient as returning a subset of columns in most cases.

Comment: @banncee : you are right. It returns the whole object