# Hibernate query error while extracting date

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datetime, jhipster

### Please, see UPDATE after error log

---

I have such a code in the spring app:

```
@Query("SELECT e.status FROM EquipmentContract e")
List<String> getTerminationDates();
```

and it works. But if I change the query, adding the field of `datetime` type

```
@Query("SELECT e.status, e.terminated_date FROM EquipmentContract e")
```

it doesn't, exposing me an error log like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration' defined in file [C:\Users\sergei.klevtsov\Documents\Projects\Work\ntt-inventory\target\classes\com\acn\inventory\config\SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 5; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'equipmentContractRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.acn.inventory.repository.EquipmentContractRepository.getTerminationDates()!
```

should there be some additional construction used in the query to handle `datatime` or...?

---

After some changes the error while compilation is gone, but now after loading REST source it says:

```
{
  "type" : "http://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "Internal Server Error",
  "status" : 500,
  "detail" : "Could not write JSON: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])",
  "path" : "/api/equipment-contracts/terminations/dates",
  "message" : "error.http.500"
}
```

it seems to me that solution is near (?)

Comment: Is the result type still List<String>? Spring does not know how to pack two values into a  single String. You should change it to either List<Object[]>, or create a separate interface for selecting just these two data items, like List<StatusAndDate>.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring JPA selecting specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns)