# Hibernate JPA Load selected column in entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with `500` columns. However, i only need `100` columns in a few scenarios.The required column list changes as per configuration.

**e.g**

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select NAME, AGE from CUSTOMER",Customer.class);
```

It is throwing an error for missing columns.

Is there any way to load selected columns in entity and ignore others.

Comment: Please post your `Customer` class. And also go through [Spring JPA selecting specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns)

Comment: Why does your entity have 500 columns? There's about 450 columns too many in there.

Comment: As I stated in the question, the Column list is not fixed. So I can not write a fixed query or Resultset mapping.                                                                  User can change the configuration in running application and column set change accordingly. For example, I may need to load the name and age both column or only name. So I need something dynamic so that I can select fields as per configuration and load entities

Answer (score 0):

You can use projections see  [Projections tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-projections)

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
criteria = criteria.setProjection(
Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.id())
.add(Projections.property("name")));
```

Comment: It is returning list of Object in restult set. I need it in form of Entity.  List of Product.

Comment: you can get list of entities  List<Product> list = criteria.list();