# How to get specific fields from OneToOne relation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have Result entity and User entity and they are linked via @OneToOne annotation:

```
@OneToOne
@MapsId
private User user;
```

and

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Result result;
```

but when I try to get all results via ajax:

```
resultRepo.findAll()
```

results are coming with users with all user fields including password and etc. How to get only specific fields from User entity when I request all results ?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns

Comment: Don't use entities as DTOs, and vice versa.

Comment: @JimmyB can you post a link to read more about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @JsonIgnore on your field and it will not show in json repsonse

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the solution. It's works. But what about if a Entity is used by other places and there do not want to use JsonIgnore.

Comment: If you have a different structure for your response, then you might wanna have a different DTO, @RohitSharma