# Close projection doesn't give result for native query in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am learning spring data close projection. However, it does not give the expected results. This means, instead of the expected interface, it gives `org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy`. I have researched this for days and I couldn't find the solution. I have attached my code as well.

**Entity class - Agent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBLDMS_AGENT")
public class Agent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AGENT_ID")
    private long agentId;
    @Column(name = "AGENT_NAME")
    private String agentName;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "CONTACT_NO")
    private String contactNo;
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private boolean status;
    @Column(name = "PROFILE_ID")
    private int profileId;
```

**Repository - AgentRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface AgentRepository extends JpaRepository<Agent, Long> {

    @Query(value = 
            "SELECT AGENT_NAME, " +
            "       PROFILE_CODE " +
            "FROM   TBLDMS_AGENT " +
            "WHERE  CONTACT_NO = :number", nativeQuery = true)
    List<AgentInformation> findByContactNumber(@Param("number") String number);


    public static interface AgentInformation {
        String getAgentName();
        String getProfileCode();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
        com.dms.agentmanagementservice.persister.AgentRepository.AgentInformation agent = agentRepository.findByContactNumber(number);
        String agentName = agent.getAgentName();
        String profileId = agent.getProfileCode();
```

But and getting `null` values for both `agentName` and `profileId`. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: try having this `AgentInformation` outside of `AgentRepository`

Comment: @Deadpool I have tried. But not working. Also tried with adding `@Projection` annotation.

Comment: Do you really need the native query in your repository?

Comment: I Don't think it's directly related to the issue but aren't you mixing up profileId and profileCode ?

Comment: @EnricoGiurin No I am not. I just want to select the field without unwanted fields.

Comment: @iuhettiarachchi maybe this will help you. Still selected fields but not native query. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020641/379173