# How to solve error " error in your SQL syntax" in JPA for custom repository

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am developing an application with spring boot. While using JPA, i am getting error that error in SQL syntax.

```
public interface ReservoirRepository extends CrudRepository<Reservoir, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "From reservoir where patientID = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Reservoir> findByPatientId(Integer patientId);
}
```

Here is the MySQL table and data

[image]

The error description is like this

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From reservoir where patientID = 1' at line 1
```

Please help me i am not getting what's wrong here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the full sql command, as its native query.  Like 
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Reservoir res where res.patientID = ?1", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: Thanks @Madhav, it worked. If you don't mind i want to ask one question. 
I want only level value from table so i wrote like this 

public interface ReservoirRepository extends CrudRepository<Reservoir, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "Select res.reservoirId, res.level From reservoir res where res.patientID = ?1 and res.type = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Reservoir> findByPatientIdAndType(Integer patientId, Integer type);
}
but i am getting exception as by stating that "java.sql.SQLException: Column 'patientID' not found."

It will be great if you help me to get this. Thanks

Comment: AND 

In the above query execution, i got full reservoir object including patient object even though i have added annotation 

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "patientID")
    private Patient patient;


in Reservoir class. So why it's not working ?

Comment: As far as your requirement to read specific column rather than full row, its not possible the way you are doing, as result and java object mapping will not work. I don't have specific answer for that , just read this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns

Comment: For second one as well i don't have any specific answer especially as i can't see full declaration and configuration. For that as well, if you have followed any article/blog then recheck your implementation to check if anything missing. Or explore articles on spring data jpa lazy loading