# How can i return only specific information with findAll() instead of everything?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dto, findall

for example i have Repository class :

```
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person>
```

and i want to use findAll() method provided by JpaSpecificationExecutor.

if i want to get all users it returns full user DTO-s including encripted passwords and user roles etc...

```
PersonRepo.findAll()
```

How can i tell findAll to send only name and email for example instead of everything.

I use Mapstruct to convert my Person Class to PersonDTO.

Comment: Leave findAll() as it is . You can create your method that calls findAll() and stores in local List. Then you can filter what you want and return new List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020641/8458501), you will have to define your own method and use the `@Query` annotation for it.

Comment: @giliermo if you find my answer helpful it will be nice to accept it as an answer.