# Spring data jpa - error - with enum type argument

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having a problem with the following code

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController' defined in file [C:\Users\USERNAME\IdeaProjects...\application\ui\security\controller\LoginController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\USERNAME\IdeaProjects\...\core\domain\login\LoginServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginRepository' defined in be.mypackage.core.persistence.LoginRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DomainConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List be.mypackage.core.persistence.LoginRepository.findListIdentifiant()!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\USERNAME\IdeaProjects\....\core\domain\login\LoginServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginRepository' defined in be.mypackage.core.persistence.LoginRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DomainConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List be.mypackage.core.persistence.LoginRepository.findListIdentifiant()!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginRepository' defined in be.mypackage.core.persistence.LoginRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DomainConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List be.mypackage.core.persistence.LoginRepository.findListIdentifiant()!

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List be.mypackage.core.persistence.LoginRepository.findListIdentifiant()!


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'loginRole' {originalText=loginRole}


Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'loginRole' {originalText=loginRole}
```

I'm trying to retrieve some value from the table but not all of it. And I have this error.
I don't want to use @Transient because it prevents me from retrieving the password value at another time.

the problem seems to be with the enum field, if I remove it from the query, with an appropriate constructor, the query no longer returns an error when launching the program.

There must be something simple that I'm not doing right.

**my request jpa**

```java
import be.mypackage.core.domain.login.Login;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository; 
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query; 

import java.util.List;  

public interface LoginRepository extends JpaRepository<Login, Integer> {

@Query(value = "SELECT idLogin, identifiant, societe, loginRole FROM Login")
 List<Login> findListIdentifiant();

}
```

**My Class entity Login**

```java
package be.mypackage.core.domain.login;

import be.mypackage.core.domain.societe.Societe;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE login SET status_actif = false WHERE id_login=?")
@Where(clause = "status_actif <> 'false'")
public class Login {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idLogin;

    @Column(length = 100, unique = true)
    private String identifiant;

    //@Transient
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String motDePasse;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // OK
    @JoinColumn(name = "no_societe", nullable = false)
    private Societe societe;

    @Transient
    @Column(name = "status_actif", nullable = false)
    private Boolean statusActif;

    @PrePersist
    public void fixStatusActif() {
        this.statusActif = true;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role", unique = true, length = 30)
    private LoginRole loginRole;

    public Login() {
    }

    // jpa request work with this constructor
    public Login(Integer idLogin, String identifiant, Societe societe) {
        this.idLogin = idLogin;
        this.identifiant = identifiant;
        this.societe = societe;
    }

    // not work
    public Login(Integer idLogin, String identifiant, Societe societe, LoginRole loginRole) {
        this.idLogin = idLogin;
        this.identifiant = identifiant;
        this.societe = societe;
        this.loginRole = loginRole;
    }

    public Integer getIdLogin() {
        return idLogin;
    }

    public void setIdLogin(Integer idLogin) {
        this.idLogin = idLogin;
    }

    public String getIdentifiant() {
        return identifiant;
    }

    public void setIdentifiant(String identifiant) {
        this.identifiant = identifiant;
    }

    public String getMotDePasse() {
        return motDePasse;
    }

    public void setMotDePasse(String motDePasse) {
        this.motDePasse = motDePasse;
    }

    public Boolean getStatusActif() {
        return statusActif;
    }

    public void setStatusActif(Boolean statusActif) {
        this.statusActif = statusActif;
    }

    public Societe getSociete() {
        return societe;
    }

    public void setSociete(Societe societe) {
        this.societe = societe;
    }

    public LoginRole getLoginRole() {
        return loginRole;
    }

    public void setLoginRole(LoginRole loginRole) {
        this.loginRole = loginRole;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return identifiant;
    }
}
```

**Class Enum**

```java
package be.mypackage.core.domain.login;
  public enum LoginRole {      
    ROLE_ADMIN,     
    ROLE_MANAGER,     
    ROLE_EMPLOYEE,     
    ROLE_EMPLOYEE_READ;
  }
```

**my table login**
[image]

---

findAll query works fine with enum but I can't exclude password from query

[image]

[image]

as you can see the role (enum) field is well getter with findAll but does not meet my security requirements

Comment: Try it with nativeQuery = true like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns)

Comment: i will try this tonight, but i guess i would have to redo the mapping manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to list the attributes in the query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT idLogin, identifiant, societe, loginRole FROM Login")
List<Login> findListIdentifiant();
```

Change to:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT l FROM Login l")
List<Login> findListIdentifiant();
```

But this query is superfluous at all because there is a `findAll()` method on JpaRepository that does exactly does that.

Comment: findAll query works fine with enum but I can't exclude password from query (see pictures in the post)

Comment: And this is a problem? I mean isn't the password encrypted? And if you want to return it in a REST API you can add @JsonIgnore to exclude it from serialization

Comment: No, the password is not encrypted, this is part of the manager's requirements ... To recover the application password. (Yes that is not very good) But your remark is not bad, I will submit it to my manager.

Comment: Moreover this is a swing app. Isn't there a way to get an enum with jpa? (Yet he says this is supported since version 2.1)

Comment: The problem is you cannot load partial entities. But you could create a regular class with a constructor that takes all the attributes. Do you know how constructor expression works?

Comment: i don't speak english very well but i guess talking to you about DTO, i just recreated this but it looks like there was an error the first time i used it so i had to give up. But it seems that the solution was there, it works.

Comment: ```@Query(value = "SELECT NEW be.mypackage.core.dto.LoginDTO (l.idLogin, l.identifiant, l.societe, l.loginRole) FROM Login l") List<LoginDTO> findListIdentifiant();```

Comment: ```Hibernate: 
    select
        login0_.id_login as col_0_0_,
        login0_.identifiant as col_1_0_,
        login0_.no_societe as col_2_0_,
        login0_.role as col_3_0_ 
    from
        login login0_ 
    inner join
        societe societe1_ 
            on login0_.no_societe=societe1_.id_societe 
    where
        (
            login0_.status_actif <> 'false'
        )```

Comment: I mark this as resolved, thanks for helping me find my error in my code.