# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:could not execute query] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm doing a house rental application with Spring, React and MySQL. I have a class which is like a transaction. What I'm trying to do is to get all entries for the class sweetholiday_user_house, but I only want the fields start_rent_date and end_rent_date.
The table is called sweet_holiday_user_house. For that I have created a SQL query in my repository:

```
package ch.ak.sweetholiday.sweetholidaybe.repository;

import ch.ak.sweetholiday.sweetholidaybe.model.SweetholidayUserHouse;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface SweetholidayUserHouseRepository extends JpaRepository<SweetholidayUserHouse, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT sweetholiday_user_house.start_rent_date, sweetholiday_user_house.end_rent_date FROM sweetholiday_user_house", nativeQuery = true)
    List<SweetholidayUserHouse> findAllReserved();
}
```

As soon as the method "findAllReserved" gets called, I get the following error message:

```
TransactionSafe called.
2021-12-25 21:44:28.711  WARN 57746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2021-12-25 21:44:28.711 ERROR 57746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id' not found.
2021-12-25 21:44:28.760 ERROR 57746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT sweetholiday_user_house.start_rent_date, sweetholiday_user_house.end_rent_date FROM sweetholiday_user_house]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
```

I tried it with the JPQL query, but it still doesn't work. I'm writing because I couldn't find a solution for it anywhere. I also don't want to use @JSONIgnore because I need the id and the foreign ids like house_id for another API call. I'm doing this because I don't want to send all information to everyone. Because when I send the foreign ids like user_id, everyone will have access to every user data.

[The class in phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPd1t.png)

The class in my Spring application:

```java
package ch.ak.sweetholiday.sweetholidaybe.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "sweetholiday_user_house")
public class SweetholidayUserHouse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sweetholiday_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SweetholidayUser sweetholidayUser;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "house_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private House house;

    @Column(name = "transaction_date")
    private LocalDateTime transaction_date;

    @Column(name = "start_rent_date")
    private LocalDateTime start_rent_date;

    @Column(name = "end_rent_date")
    private LocalDateTime end_rent_date;

    @Column(name = "options")
    private String options;

    @Column(name = "payment")
    private String payment;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public SweetholidayUser getSweetholidayUser() {
        return sweetholidayUser;
    }

    public void setSweetholidayUser(SweetholidayUser sweetholidayUser) {
        this.sweetholidayUser = sweetholidayUser;
    }

    public House getHouse() {
        return house;
    }

    public void setHouse(House house) {
        this.house = house;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTransaction_date() {
        return transaction_date;
    }

    public void setTransaction_date(LocalDateTime transaction_date) {
        this.transaction_date = transaction_date;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStart_rent_date() {
        return start_rent_date;
    }

    public void setStart_rent_date(LocalDateTime start_rent_date) {
        this.start_rent_date = start_rent_date;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEnd_rent_date() {
        return end_rent_date;
    }

    public void setEnd_rent_date(LocalDateTime end_rent_date) {
        this.end_rent_date = end_rent_date;
    }

    public String getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(String options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public String getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }

    public void setPayment(String payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
    }
}
```

The method gets called like that:

```
@Override
public List<SweetholidayUserHouse> findAllTransactionsSafe() {
    return sweetholidayUserHouseRepository.findAllReserved();
}
```

Here is the full error message if you need it:

```
TransactionSafe called.
2021-12-25 21:44:28.711  WARN 57746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2021-12-25 21:44:28.711 ERROR 57746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id' not found.
2021-12-25 21:44:28.760 ERROR 57746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT sweetholiday_user_house.start_rent_date, sweetholiday_user_house.end_rent_date FROM sweetholiday_user_house]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:581) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:854) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:735) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2195) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1190) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:128) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy116.findAllReserved(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at ch.ak.sweetholiday.sweetholidaybe.service.SweetholidayUserHouseServiceImpl.findAllTransactionsSafe(SweetholidayUserHouseServiceImpl.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at ch.ak.sweetholiday.sweetholidaybe.service.SweetholidayUserHouseServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$376f23f9.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at ch.ak.sweetholiday.sweetholidaybe.service.SweetholidayUserHouseServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6cbff5.findAllTransactionsSafe(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at ch.ak.sweetholiday.sweetholidaybe.controller.UserController.getSafeTransaction(UserController.java:104) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at ch.ak.sweetholiday.sweetholidaybe.jwt.JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthorizationFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting a subset (`start_rent_date and end_rent_date`) of the columns of the table `sweetholiday_user_house`. However the results are being mapped to the managed entity `SweetholidayUserHouse`. So the mapping fails when it looks for the id column in the resultset, which is missing.

You can avoid this exception by either of these two approaches. There are several more. Here is a good discussion of this - [Spring JPA selecting specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns)

Option 1: Keep the existing query and change the return type of the findAllReserved() method to `Object[]`. Here for each Object[], Object[0] is start_rent_date and Object[1] is end_rent_date.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT sweetholiday_user_house.start_rent_date, sweetholiday_user_house.end_rent_date FROM sweetholiday_user_house", nativeQuery = true)

List<Object[]> findAllReserved();
```

Option 2: Keep the return type and change the query to JPA query (non-native) to return all the columns. This will map all the columns to the Hibernate Object.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user FROM sweetholiday_user_house user")
List<SweetholidayUserHouse> findAllReserved();
```