# How to select only specific columns in a micronaut query

Tags: micronaut

I am using micronaut in backend and I have a table called `transactions` in postgres which has about 11 columns in it. I want to make a query to select only 4 columns from it.

We also did a look at [this stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns) but it does not help in micronaut. Official [Docs](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#sql) also does not provide precise answers for the same. We did google lot of stuffs about this and finally solved by doing this:

---

1. Created a DTO record for the same

**MonthlyTransactionDTO.java**

```java
package com.example.transactions.dto;

import java.util.Date;

public record MonthlyTransactionDTO(Long id, Long userId, Date dateOfTransaction, double amount) {
}
```

2. Customised the query in repository class

**transactionsRepository.java**

```java
@Repository
public interface TransactionsRepository extends CrudRepository<Transaction, Long> {
  @Query(value ="select new com.example.transactions.dto.MonthlyTransactionDTO(T.id, T.userId, T.dateOfTransaction, T.amount) from transactions T")
  List<MonthlyTransactionDTO> findMonthlyTransactionsDetails(Long userId);
}
```

---

**My question is: Is there any other nice way in which we can achieve to select specific columns or a way where I can write my custom SQL query in a clean way?**

TBH, I really don't like this kind of approach to select specific columns from Database. Coz everytime when I change my package name I have to change this `com.example.transactions.dto.` manually coz intelliJ does not auto detect it.

Would be very helpful if you could give me any leads or anything for the same problem. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you need the `@Query` annotation?  (see https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/3.3.0/guide/#dto for examples)

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I don't get it how should I implement this. And what if I have another situation where I have to select only 3 columns.. I am new to micronaut. So ..

Comment: "And what if I have another situation where I have to select only 3 columns." - Is your goal to have a single method that supports all of your situations?

Comment: It would be good if single method can do that. But even if it does not, its okay for now

Comment: I believe that regardless of whether or not you are using `@Query` you will need separate methods if you have situations that require selecting different subsets of columns.

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: "How can I achieve this?" - If you mean "How to select only only specific columns in micronaut query", you can have a repository method which returns a DTO and the properties in the DTO dictate which columns are selected from the table(s).

Comment: How can I  "dictate which columns are selected from the table(s)". If its possible can you please post answer to how to actually code this

Comment: "How can I "dictate which columns are selected from the table(s)".  The columns selected from the database correspond to properties in the DTO. If you want the column selected, add a corresponding property to the DTO.  If you do not want a column selected, do not include a corresponding property in the DTO.  I think there are good examples at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/3.3.0/guide/#dto.  That page includes "Micronaut Data will optimize the query to only select the necessary properties from the database.".