# Derived Query for distinct object using JPA is not returning proper result

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a entity class

```
public class Hex {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "native")
    @Column(name = "hex_id")
    private Long hexId;

    @Column(name = "class")
    String vehicleClass;

    @Column(name = "manufacturer")
    String manufacturer;

}
```

I need distinct manufacturer on basis of Vehicleclass, I am using below function

```
    List<Hex> findManufacturerDistinctByVehicleClass(String classId);
```

But this return Distinct Hex objects on the basis of vehicle ID ,I observed the query in console and it was fetching results based on distinct primary key and applying a where clause on class

```
   select
        distinct hex0_.hex_id as hex_id1_1_,
        hex0_.Manufacturer as manufact2_1_,
        hex0_.class as class3_1_ 
    from
        hex hex0_ 
    where
        hex0_.class=?
```

I can do it by using @Query but I am looking for a derived query solution and if cannot be done then why

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40934100/14624844 Does this answer help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is [how derived queries work](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation):

- Anything between `find` and `By` is skipped, except for the `Distinct` keyword
- `Distinct` will apply the distinct keyword to the select clause of the SQL query
- Everything after `By` is used in the where clause as a filter (it won't affect the select clause)

I think you already know this but I guess you have two options:

- The `@Query` annotation:

  ```
  @Query("select distinct manufacturer from Hex where ...")
  List<String> findManufacturerDistinctByVehicleClass(String classId);
  ```
- [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces):

  ```
  interface ManufacturerProjection {
      String getManufacturer();
  }

  List<ManufacturerProjection> findManufacturerDistinctByVehicleClass(String classId);
  ```