# How to retrieve all user information except passwords

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I implemented a basic JPA authentication following [this tutorial](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-security-authentication-with-jpa-hibernate-and-mysql).

I wanted to create an endpoint `/mydetails` to display user information (profile info).

What I've tried:

```
@GetMapping("/mydetails")
public Optional<User> getUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Optional<User> foundUser = Optional.ofNullable(userRepo.getUserByUsername(request.getUserPrincipal().getName()));
    return foundUser;
}
```

Outcome:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "username":"name.surname@companyname.com",
  "password":"$2a$10$7YzUO6scaC06LV6IgOsSXetFm4/U0WM.UZykhRfQcJBzKacyZFMK",
  "first_name":"John",
  "last_name":"Walker",
  "organization_name":"ABC",
  "role":"Admin",
  "credibility_rating":"100"
}
```

The problem is that this literally takes out all the information and I want everything except the password.

How could I stop the response from sending the password information?

I am totally new to Spring and have not used Java for many years.

Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Comment: why would you even store a password? never store a password, always only a hashed value. If this way doesn't do as you want, you could always use projections, I guess: check this answer. I think it suits your needs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns

Comment: Additionally, use DTO's as return values instead of the entity itself. If you don't want to do that, just set the password to a null value, before returning it.

Comment: Additionally to the additionally :D - Instead of wrapping the result of `userRepo.getUserByUsername(...)` in an Optional, just adjust the return type of the interface: `Optional<User> findUserByUsername(String username);`.

Comment: @Stultuske Storing the hashed password is exactly what OP (Spring Security) is doing...

Comment: @rolve in which case the password isn't returned

Comment: @Stultuske True, but irrelevant. OP asked how to stop sending "the password information", which includes the password hash. A sensible thing to do anyway, even though the hash should in theory be safe to expose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are talking about a REST controller that returns JSON. With the default configuration, Spring Boot uses [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) to transform objects to JSON. The most simple fix would be to tell Jackson to [ignore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) the `password` field in your `User` class:

```
public class User {
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    ...
}
```

See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization#for_field) for more information.