# Selecting property from dependent entity in a HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have following entity:

```
@Entity
class A {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
   String id;
        //some field        

   @ManyToMany
   Set<B> other;
}

@Entity
class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    String id;
    //some field
}
```

I would like to create `hql` query which list `ids` of B for `A` entity contained in `Set<B>`.

Somethig like (incorrect):

```
select a.other.id from A as a where a.id = :pid
```

Comment: What's the exception thrown and how are you calling it from hibernate. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807698/how-to-retrieve-only-certain-fields-of-an-entity-in-jpql-or-hql-what-is-the-equ

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
select a.other.id from A a join a.other o where a.id = :pid
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I'm not sure but I *think* you ought to use the alias in the projection (so `select o.id ...`).

Comment: No did not test it, it was something i thought i remembered about, sorry.